# VB Visual Studio - Can't change cell format for more than one DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I have 13 DataGridViews on one form. I can change the format of the cells in the first DataGridView but when I try to do the same with the other 12 DataGridViews, nothing changes. Here is an example of code that I am using that has this effect:

```
Private Sub Compare_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Compare.Click
    Dim Recipe As Integer = Nothing
    Dim DataGridViews = {DataGridView1, DataGridView2, DataGridView3, DataGridView4, DataGridView5, DataGridView6,
        DataGridView7, DataGridView8, DataGridView9, DataGridView10, DataGridView11, DataGridView12, DataGridView13}

    'Get user input for recipe to compare to current values.
    Recipe = InputBox("Enter the recipe number you wish to compare the current values to.  E.g., '0', '1', '2', etc.")

    For Each DataGridView In DataGridViews
        For i As Integer = 5 To 36
            DataGridView.Columns(i).Visible = False
        Next
        DataGridView.Columns(Recipe + 5).Visible = True
    Next

    For Each DataGridView In DataGridViews

        For i As Integer = 2 To DataGridView.DisplayedRowCount(False) - 1
            If DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(Recipe + 5).Value And
        DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value <> Nothing Then
                DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow
                DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(Recipe + 5).Style.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow
            ElseIf DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value <> DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(Recipe + 5).Value And
            DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value <> Nothing Then
                DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
                DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(Recipe + 5).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: First, turn on Option Strict.  If you use some of the many events the DGV has available, you wont need to loop thru the rows

Comment: Enable [Option Strict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2454583/2592875) and the IDE will direct you to correct the likely source of your problem.

Comment: I turned on Option Strict and there was no change - the app still runs as normal with the first DataGridView working and the other 13 not. There are also no additional warnings.

Comment: `I turned on Option Strict ... There are also no additional warnings.`  -- Not likely. `DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(Recipe + 5).Value` will not compile with Option Strict On.  Update your code to show the typed value comparisons.  Do not use `Value.ToString` unless the value is truly a `String` type.

Comment: I am guessing something else is going on. I recommend you trace the code to see if it actually gets to the cell style change line of code after the first grid. My test using “3” as the input and setting columns 3 and 9 to the same value, turned the cells yellow green for all grids, in addition it turned the cells red when the values did not match. Something else is going on.

Comment: In addition, I would highly “discourage” you from naming a variable a “class” name. The `For Each DataGridView in DataGridViews` line looks strange in a sense that `DataGridView` is a “CLASS” and you are using it like a variable, which obviously the compiler is not caring about. This is a bad practice and I would change the name of the variable to a more meaningful name that is not going to create ambiguity.

Comment: I have now found that if I view the DataGridView before applying the formatting changes, they all work. So if I cycle through all 13 tabs and then press the button that makes the format changes, the format changes occur. If I haven't opened a tab before applying changes, that tab will not change.

Comment: Any "formatting" changes on the grid will be "ignored" if is not displayed!